# ggplot2 dollar_format on large numbers yields scientific notation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the new dollar_format() syntax in ggplot, I get unexpected behavior. Is there (yet) another argument to pass to make the sci-not go away?

```
x <- seq(0,100000,10000)
[1] 0e+00 1e+04 2e+04 3e+04 4e+04 5e+04 6e+04 7e+04 8e+04 9e+04 1e+05
dollar(x)
[1] "$0e+00" "$1e+04" "$2e+04" "$3e+04" "$4e+04" "$5e+04" "$6e+04" "$7e+04" "$8e+04" "$9e+04" "$1e+05"
```

Comment: I think this may be a bug. The call to `format` should probably specify `scientific = FALSE`.

Comment: This behavior will no longer occur in the next release of `scales` (which would be no later than the next release of `ggplot2`): https://github.com/hadley/scales/pull/17

Comment: just noticed you added this on github. Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `dollar` function is now in the `scales` package.  You can keep it from switching to scientific notation using the `scipen` option. Note that this will affect ALL your output, not just this formatting.

```
> options(scipen=5)
> dollar(x)
 [1] "$0"       "$10,000"  "$20,000"  "$30,000"  "$40,000"  "$50,000"  "$60,000" 
 [8] "$70,000"  "$80,000"  "$90,000"  "$100,000"
```

As @joran said, though, `dollar` probably should not allow scientific notation at all.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, something like this should work:

```
dollar1 <- function (x) 
{
  x <- round_any(x, 0.01)
  nsmall <- if (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) < 100) 
    2
  else 0
  stringr::str_c("$", format(x, nsmall = nsmall, trim = TRUE, big.mark = ",",scientific = FALSE))
}
```

If you don't want to call `str_c` directly using `::` you'll need to make sure that the `stringr` library is loaded.